# How to upload a file to an endpoint from an integration test

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, moq, integration-testing

When a file is uploaded from the client, it can be found in `this.Request.Files`, which is of type `HttpFileCollectionBase`.

`HttpFileCollectionBase` contains `HttpPostedFileBase` entries.

The properties on these objects are read-only, so I was hoping I could setup some mocks. My mock request would return a mock `HttpFileCollection`, and that collection would contain one mock`HttpPostedFile`. The `InputStream` property on that object would return a `FileStream` object that I would instantiate using a real file in source control.

1. Is this a good approach to uploading
   a file to an endpoint from an
   integration test?
2. If it is a good approach, how can I mock this out
   with `Moq`?
3. If this is not a good approach, can you suggest a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know nothing about asp.net mvc, but it looks like you would need to do something like this to setup your mock dependencies:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

var mockFile = new Mock<HttpPostedFileBase>();
var mockFiles = new Mock<HttpFileCollectionBase>();
var mockRequest = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();

mockFile.Setup(f => f.InputStream).Returns(stream);

// if for example, you index the file by name.
mockFiles.Setup(f => f[It.IsAny<string>()]).Returns(mockFile.Object);

mockRequest.Setup(r => r.Files).Returns(() => mockFiles.Object);

// write expected data to your memory stream, then instantiate your class 
// under test using the mockRequest.Object
```

In a unit test, I would use a memory stream rather a file, but a file stream works the same.

If you want to avoid having to mock out and set up all these dependencies, you could put them behind a `UploadedFiles` abstraction, make your code depend on the abstraction, and mock only `UploadedFiles`. This need only be a thin wrapper around `Request.Files` to get a file stream by name (or however you access them). This is better because the downstream code now depends on `UploadedFiles`, `Stream` and `string`, rather than `HttpRequestBase`, `HttpFileCollectionBase`, `HttpPostedFileBase`, `Stream` and `string`.

Setup would then be simplified to something like this:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
var mockUploadedFiles = new Mock<UploadedFiles>();
mockUploadedFiles.Setup(u => u.GetFile(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(stream);
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it would work. I will give it a shot!